# IID Random Variables that are not constant can't converge almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to prove the following.

If $\{ X_n \}$ are iid random variables and not constant, then $R:=P\{ \omega \mid  X_n(\omega)\text{ converges} \}=0$

Using independence I know that by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, that if $R$ is not $0$ then $R=1$.  So I think the way to do this proof is by contradiction.  So I am trying to show $R=1$ implies the $X_n$ are constant using their identical distribution but sadly it is not working.  Help would  be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\left\{\omega: \lim X_n(\omega)  \le c \right\}$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra for every $c$. So by Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law they have to converge to a constant if they converge.

But this can't happen if $X_n$ are not constant. Because in this case for any constant $c$ we have some $\epsilon > 0$ so that

$P(X_n(\omega) < c - \epsilon) \ge \delta > 0$ for every $n$

or $P(X_n(\omega) > c + \epsilon) \ge \delta > 0$ for every $n$.

In either case, we see that $X_n(\omega)$ cannot converge to $c$ almost surely.

Comment: How do you know your second sentence.  "But this ... for every n"

Comment: If $X_1$ is not $c$ almost surely then it must be bounded away from $c$ with positive probability. Then the $X_n$ are i.i.d. so they all enjoy this same positive probability bound away from $c$.

Comment: Forgot about the i.d. part, of course.  I been working too much today.  Time to go to bed haha.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. You have $\{\omega: \lim X_n(\omega)=c\}$ has probability zero or one for every $c$. What prevents these probabilities from all being zero? As they would be, for instance, if $\lim X_n$ were a continuous random variable.

Comment: @DevenWare Actually I am not convinced that we have the bound.  Suppose $X_1$ was $c$ everywhere but on a set of measure zero.  Then doesn't that violate your argument?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland indeed you are right. But if you replace $=$ with $\le$ then you still have the claim. (They converge to the point where it shifts from being $0$ to $1$). Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @LeoSpencer Constant almost everywhere is what they mean by constant. Because if you take i.i.d. random variables, all being $1$ for $x\ne 0$ and $0$ at $x = 0$, then they converge almost surely!

Comment: @LeoSpencer I think compared to "non-constant", the word non-degenerate is better. The new word take cares of the almost surely constant.